# How can I make this table fit in landscape orientation?

Tags: tables, overleaf, excel2latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Income \& Expenditure Summary : Mar 2013 - Mar 2022 : Non-Annualised : Billion Ruppees} &         &         &          &         &         \\
\hline
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-13} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-14} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-15} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-16} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-17} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-18} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-19} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-20} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-21} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mar-22} \\
\hline
Total income                               & 95.988     & 117.031    & 137.491    & 162.655    & 205.868   & 254.926 & 342.149 & 398.642  & 236.007 & 223.274 \\
Income from financial services             & 95.956     & 116.07     & 137.491    & 162.533    & 203.778   & 251.505 & 337.354 & 290.795  & 228.697 & 215.526 \\
Interest income                            & 82.94      & 99.814     & 115.72     & 135.335    & 164.247   & 202.675 & 296.248 & 260.667  & 200.419 & 190.236 \\
Dividends                                  & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Income from treasury operations            & 2.254      & 3.647      & 2.006      & 2.607      & 8.132     & 7.451   & 4.746   & 14.867   & 15.926  & 8.911   \\
Other income                               & 0          & 0.961      & 0          & 0.098      & 2.037     & 3.422   & 4.791   & 88.434   & 3.966   & 7.461   \\
Prior period and extraordinary income      & 0.033      & 0          & 0          & 0.024      & 0.055     & 0       & 0.004   & 19.415   & 3.345   & 0.289   \\
                                           & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Total expenses                             & 82.982     & 100.87     & 117.437    & 137.261    & 172.567   & 212.68  & 324.947 & 562.823  & 270.629 & 212.612 \\
Operating Expenses                         & 73.987     & 90.379     & 103.558    & 118.527    & 146.249   & 177.722 & 264.61  & 321.369  & 200.03  & 197.621 \\
Fee based financial services expenses      & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Fund based financial services expenses     & 60.753     & 73.511     & 81.513     & 89.869     & 106.796   & 127.903 & 204.982 & 257.433  & 145.643 & 133.161 \\
Interest expenses                          & 60.753     & 72.651     & 80.842     & 89.668     & 106.274   & 125.304 & 198.158 & 192.614  & 129.477 & 125.257 \\
Treasury operations expenses               & 0          & 0.861      & 0.671      & 0.201      & 0.523     & 2.6     & 6.825   & 64.82    & 16.166  & 7.904   \\
Compensation to employees                  & 6.556      & 7.844      & 9.797      & 12.968     & 18.051    & 21.89   & 24.698  & 25.999   & 24.304  & 28.557  \\
Indirect taxes                             & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Rent \& lease rent                         & 1.812      & 2.292      & 2.664      & 3.048      & 3.792     & 4.544   & 4.174   & 4.463    & 4.405   & 3.948   \\
Repairs \& maintenance                     & 0.092      & 0.111      & 0.159      & 0.16       & 0.203     & 0.346   & 0.421   & 0.352    & 0.322   & 0.365   \\
Insurance premium paid                     & 0.449      & 0.529      & 0.692      & 0.936      & 1.197     & 1.513   & 2.079   & 2.162    & 1.358   & 2.01    \\
Outsourced professional jobs               & 0.027      & 0.025      & 0.02       & 0.032      & 0.05      & 0.075   & 0.115   & 0.195    & 0.228   & 0.436   \\
Non-executive directors' fees              & 0.006      & 0.006      & 0.012      & 0.013      & 0.03      & 0.02    & 0.044   & 0.055    & 0.029   & 0.045   \\
Selling \& distribution expenses           & 0.323      & 0.597      & 0.703      & 0.836      & 1.005     & 0.96    & 0.649   & 0.275    & 0.364   & 0.244   \\
Travel expenses                            & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Communications expenses                    & 0.159      & 0.248      & 0.305      & 0.361      & 0.486     & 0.605   & 0.648   & 0.644    & 0.449   & 0.448   \\
Printing \& stationery expenses            & 0.113      & 0.132      & 0.168      & 0.184      & 0.272     & 0.369   & 0.424   & 0.394    & 0.298   & 0.311   \\
Miscellaneous expenditure                  & 3.701      & 5.088      & 7.687      & 10.421     & 14.788    & 19.954  & 26.919  & 29.807   & 22.636  & 28.1    \\
                                           & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Non-Cash Charges                           & 2.739      & 3.389      & 4.83       & 6.467      & 9.179     & 15.249  & 53.967  & 285.533  & 83.293  & 11.169  \\
Provisions                                 & 2.222      & 2.757      & 3.979      & 5.361      & 7.466     & 12.939  & 50.951  & 282.177  & 79.761  & 7.186   \\
Depreciation                               & 0.518      & 0.632      & 0.851      & 1.106      & 1.713     & 2.31    & 3.016   & 3.357    & 3.533   & 3.984   \\
Amortisation                               & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Write-offs                                 & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
                                           & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Prior period and extraordinary expenses    & 0.007      & 0.019      & 0.002      & 0.001      & 0         & 0.013   & 0       & 0        & 0.035   & 0.126   \\
                                           & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
Provision for direct tax                   & 6.251      & 7.085      & 9.048      & 12.268     & 17.141    & 19.698  & 6.371   & -44.079  & -12.729 & 3.697   \\
                                           & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0          & 0         & 0       & 0       & 0        & 0       & 0       \\
PAT (Profit after tax)                     & 13.006     & 16.161     & 20.054     & 25.394     & 33.301    & 42.246  & 17.203  & -164.181 & -34.623 & 10.663 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (special case of[page breaking - My table doesn't fit; what are my options? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Answer (score 1):

Your table is slightly to big. Try the following:

- slightly increase text area size (by reducing pages' borders)
- reducing `\tabcolsep`
- in table use `\small` font size
- using `S` columns of `siunitx` for aligning numbers at decimal points

All this can be simple to obtain by use `tabularray` package.

Off-topic:

- why you use `threeparttable`?
- it seems that first table row is actually caption of tale, why then is not write as caption?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}  % make text block larger
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{tblr}{colsep =4pt,
                 colspec={@{} l *{10}{X[c,si={table-format=3.3}]} @{}},
                 rowsep=0pt,
                 row{1,2} = {mode=text, guard},
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=12]{l}   Income \& Expenditure Summary: Mar 2013 - Mar 2022: Non-Annualised: Billion Ruppees
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    \midrule
    &   Mar-13  &   Mar-14  &   Mar-15  &   Mar-16  &   Mar-17   
    &   Mar-18  &   Mar-19  &   Mar-20  &   Mar-21  &   Mar-22      \\
    \midrule
Total income                               
    & 95.988    & 117.031   & 137.491   & 162.655   & 205.868   
    & 254.926   & 342.149   & 398.642   & 236.007   & 223.274       \\
Income from financial services             
    & 95.956    & 116.07    & 137.491   & 162.533   & 203.778   
    & 251.505   & 337.354   & 290.795   & 228.697   & 215.526       \\
Interest income                            
    & 82.94     & 99.814    & 115.72    & 135.335   & 164.247   
    & 202.675   & 296.248   & 260.667   & 200.419   & 190.236       \\
Dividends                                  
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Income from treasury operations            
    & 2.254     & 3.647     & 2.006     & 2.607     & 8.132     
    & 7.451     & 4.746     & 14.867    & 15.926    & 8.911         \\
Other income                               
    & 0         & 0.961     & 0         & 0.098     & 2.037     
    & 3.422     & 4.791     & 88.434    & 3.966     & 7.461         \\
Prior period and extraordinary income      
    & 0.033     & 0         & 0         & 0.024     & 0.055     
    & 0         & 0.004     & 19.415    & 3.345     & 0.289         \\
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Total expenses                             
    & 82.982    & 100.87    & 117.437   & 137.261   & 172.567   
    & 212.68    & 324.947   & 562.823   & 270.629   & 212.612       \\
Operating Expenses                         
    & 73.987    & 90.379    & 103.558   & 118.527    & 146.249   
    & 177.722   & 264.61    & 321.369   & 200.03    & 197.621       \\
Fee based financial services expenses      
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Fund based financial services expenses     
    & 60.753    & 73.511    & 81.513    & 89.869    & 106.796   
    & 127.903   & 204.982   & 257.433   & 145.643   & 133.161       \\
Interest expenses                          
    & 60.753    & 72.651    & 80.842    & 89.668    & 106.274   
    & 125.304   & 198.158   & 192.614   & 129.477   & 125.257       \\
Treasury operations expenses               
    & 0         & 0.861     & 0.671     & 0.201     & 0.523     
    & 2.6       & 6.825     & 64.82     & 16.166    & 7.904         \\
Compensation to employees                  
    & 6.556     & 7.844     & 9.797     & 12.968    & 18.051    
    & 21.89     & 24.698    & 25.999    & 24.304    & 28.557        \\
Indirect taxes                             
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Rent \& lease rent                         
    & 1.812     & 2.292     & 2.664     & 3.048     & 3.792     
    & 4.544     & 4.174     & 4.463     & 4.405     & 3.948         \\
Repairs \& maintenance                     
    & 0.092     & 0.111     & 0.159     & 0.16      & 0.203     
    & 0.346     & 0.421     & 0.352     & 0.322     & 0.365         \\
Insurance premium paid                     
    & 0.449     & 0.529     & 0.692     & 0.936     & 1.197     
    & 1.513     & 2.079     & 2.162     & 1.358     & 2.01          \\
Outsourced professional jobs               
    & 0.027     & 0.025     & 0.02      & 0.032     & 0.05      
    & 0.075     & 0.115     & 0.195     & 0.228     & 0.436         \\
Non-executive directors' fees              
    & 0.006     & 0.006     & 0.012     & 0.013     & 0.03      
    & 0.02      & 0.044     & 0.055     & 0.029     & 0.045         \\
Selling \& distribution expenses           
    & 0.323     & 0.597     & 0.703     & 0.836     & 1.005     
    & 0.96      & 0.649     & 0.275     & 0.364     & 0.244         \\
Travel expenses                            
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Communications expenses                    
    & 0.159     & 0.248     & 0.305     & 0.361     & 0.486     
    & 0.605     & 0.648     & 0.644     & 0.449     & 0.448         \\
Printing \& stationery expenses            
    & 0.113     & 0.132     & 0.168     & 0.184     & 0.272     
    & 0.369     & 0.424     & 0.394     & 0.298     & 0.311         \\
Miscellaneous expenditure                  
    & 3.701     & 5.088     & 7.687     & 10.421    & 14.788    
    & 19.954    & 26.919    & 29.807    & 22.636    & 28.1          \\
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Non-Cash Charges                           
    & 2.739     & 3.389     & 4.83      & 6.467     & 9.179     
    & 15.249    & 53.967    & 285.533   & 83.293    & 11.169        \\
Provisions                                 
    & 2.222     & 2.757     & 3.979     & 5.361     & 7.466     
    & 12.939    & 50.951    & 282.177   & 79.761    & 7.186         \\
Depreciation                               
    & 0.518     & 0.632     & 0.851     & 1.106     & 1.713     
    & 2.31      & 3.016     & 3.357     & 3.533     & 3.984         \\
Amortisation                               
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Write-offs
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Prior period and extraordinary expenses    
    & 0.007     & 0.019     & 0.002     & 0.001     & 0         
    & 0.013     & 0         & 0         & 0.035     & 0.126         \\
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
Provision for direct tax                  
    & 6.251     & 7.085     & 9.048     & 12.268    & 17.141    
    & 19.698    & 6.371     & -44.079   & -12.729   & 3.697         \\
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0
    & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             \\
PAT (Profit after tax)                     
    & 13.006    & 16.161    & 20.054    & 25.394    & 33.301    
    & 42.246    & 17.203    & -164.181  & -34.623   & 10.663        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My friend tried out the code threeparttable….. as for myself I’m very new to latex and it’s quite frustrating working with tables in here . Thanks for helping me out !!